# Access online play on PS4 from a country with no local PSN and no foreign credit card

Tags: psn, region-lock, ps4

I can not play online on my ps4 because I need to put my billing info before using codes. The problem is I am from Qatar and I use the USA as my region for my main account. I tried making a Qatari account but it tells me there is no Qatari Store!!

How can I access PSN with billing info when I live in a region with no official PSN support and I have no credit cards from a region with PSN access?

Comment: sounds like an issue with PSN... not much we can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

[You will need valid billing information for the region matching your PSN country](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/792). Since a Qatar account is out of the question apparently, I would recommend the US store if you are fluent in English; the US store has more variety than some regions, isn't in Japanese, and I believe the UK/EU stores are a bit more expensive in some cases.

You should be able to use a prepaid credit card (which won't require actually opening an account in that region), [this forum thread indicates mixed but mostly positive success](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/Can-prepaid-Visa-or-MC-gift-cards-be-used-on-PSN/td-p/13578430), I believe they only recognize Visa and Mastercard numbers on the store. Any prepaid card with a proper credit card number (16 digits, recognized as valid) should work, though I haven't tried this myself.

Note that to actually *purchase* items on the PSN you will quickly run out of money on that prepaid card, but you can use special prepaid PSN cards (I am unsure if these are region locked, but US ones should be in good supply to import?) to add to your account without a real credit card.

Comment: PSN Cards are region locked as they only work for the PSN Account of that region (ie. AUS PSN Card will only work on a AUS PSN Account and not a UK or US one)

Comment: there also seems to be some sort of region locked with cards, i tried using an Australian Pre-paid Master Card when creating a US Account and even though i put in the information correctly it kept being declined even though i had $200 in there, even did the same with my Visa Bank Card

Comment: should point out that my posts are from PSN on a PS3, i wont have access to a PS4 until Christmas which when i do get it i will be checking if i can access all 3 of my accounts on the one system to avoid the region lock on DLC

Comment: @Memor-X interesting the prepaid cards are region locked. The PS4 should work exactly the same as the PS3. I didn't have to update billing or anything to start using the PS4 store.